# UIImageView not displaying images

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, mpmediaitem

For some reason I cannot get an image album into my UIImageView.  It is added in storyboard and declared:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *displayAlbum;
@synthesize displayAlbum, titleLbl, artist;
```

In my code:

```
displayAlbum = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

MPMediaPropertyPredicate *predicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:@"1079287588763212246" forProperty:MPMediaEntityPropertyPersistentID];
MPMediaQuery *query = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];
[query addFilterPredicate: predicate];
NSArray *queryResults = [query items];

for (MPMediaItem *song in queryResults) {
MPMediaItemArtwork *artwork = [song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
[displayAlbum setImage: [artwork imageWithSize:CGSizeMake(displayAlbum.frame.size.width, displayAlbum.frame.size.height)]];
        }
```

I am able to get other song information so its definitely getting the right song, but the `ImageView` always shows up blank.

On a side note, if anybody could help me clean up the above bit of code, especially get rid of the `for` loop  (it should always only return one result anyways) that would be great.  Thanks

Comment: one silly thing...have u added the imageView as subview to superView?

Comment: Do i have to do this even if i use IB?  I tried `[self.view addSubview:displayAlbum];` with no luck though.

Comment: R U sure that , You initialized the UIImageView with some FRAME...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're creating a new image view with alloc init, instead of using the one you created in IB. You should just delete that alloc init line.

Comment: Duh....I haven't used IB in a while and have been used to doing things programatically.  Thanks!

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference. In my case it doesn't. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you allocating displayAlbum, when it is IBOutlet? If it is already made in NIB, then by allocating new one, it should not work, as you will have completelly new UIImageView which is not part of your view controller. If it is not made in NIB, then you should add it to your view controller by adding subview of some of your views that are part of your view controller and set some frame for it.

At first, try to comment this line:

displayAlbum = [[UIImageView alloc] init];